# Higher direct images of a sheaf in Kempf's Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, presheaves

Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous mapping of topological spaces. Let $F$ be an abelian sheaf on $X$. We define $R^i f_{\star} F$ as the $i$-homology sheaf of the complex $f_{\star}(D^{\star}(F))$, where $(D^{\star}(F))$ is the usual canonical sheaf resolution used to define cohomology.

I'm really struggling trying to understand the following statement

> One way to compute $R^i f_{\star} F$ is to note that it is the sheaf associated to the presheaf $V\rightarrow H^i(f^{-1}V,F)$ for any open subset $V$ of $Y$.

Even though this sounds incredibly intuitive to me, I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: The proof I know is a $\delta$-functor argument (cf. Hartshorne III.8.1). Is this a kind of argument you're comfortable with?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have actually read the proof in Hartshorne but I'm not even remotely familiar with that language. My whole algebraic geometry knowledge comes from Kempf's book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet a full answer, but try it as an exercise: For any open $V \subset Y$ you have
$$f_*(D^\bullet F)(V) = D^\bullet F(f^{-1}V).$$
So if you take cohomology at that step, you obtain
$$H^k(f_*(D^\bullet F)(V)) = H^k(f^{-1} V, F).$$
Now it remains to show that whenever $C^\bullet$ is a cocomplex of sheaves, the cohomology *sheaves* $H^k(C^\bullet)$ are the sheaves associated to the presheaf
$$V \mapsto H^k(C^\bullet (V)).$$